# Multidimensional Matrix Transpose in Excel (Macro)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have some "multidimensional" data in an Excel spreadsheet that currently look like this below:
[image: excel matrix]

I'd like to transform this into rows with multiple columns:
[image: tabular format]

I have tried multiple macros but still can't handle all dimensions to transpose correctly to rows, would be extremely grateful for any help :)

P.

Here's the code which works well without 3rd dimension (sales type):

```
Sub test()
    Dim inputRange As Range, inputRRay As Variant
    Dim outputRange As Range, outputRRay() As Variant
    Dim outRow As Long, inCol As Long, inRow As Long

    Set inputRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AA150")
    Set outputRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    inputRRay = inputRange.Value
    ReDim outputRRay(1 To (UBound(inputRRay, 1) * UBound(inputRRay, 2)), 1 To 3)
    outRow = 0

    For inCol = 2 To UBound(inputRRay, 2)
        For inRow = 2 To UBound(inputRRay, 1)
            If inputRRay(inRow, inCol) <> vbNullString And inputRRay(inRow, inCol) <> 0 Then
                outRow = outRow + 1
                outputRRay(outRow, 1) = inputRRay(1, inCol)
                outputRRay(outRow, 2) = inputRRay(inRow, 1)
                outputRRay(outRow, 3) = inputRRay(inRow, inCol)
            End If
        Next inRow
    Next inCol
    With outputRange.Resize(1, 3)
        .EntireColumn.Clear
        .Value = Array("Store", "Product", "QTY")
        .Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
    End With
    With outputRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(outputRRay, 1), UBound(outputRRay, 2))
        .Value = outputRRay
    End With
    With outputRange.Parent
        With Range(outputRange.Range("a1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, outputRange.Column).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3)
            .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Columns.AutoFit
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd advise to try powerquery (get & transform) for this.

Comment: Can you post the code you've already tried - however faulty - as it'll give us something to work from.

Comment: Hi Ambie, I've attached the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're specifically after a VBA solution, then I think you might be over-complicating your code.

Your range definition looks odd. I don't quite see why you're selecting columns "A" to "AA" when the data is only in the first 7 columns. And the data transfer should simply be a case of looping the rows and then each column to transfer into the output array. The desired code would look something like the below. I've left all the formatting bits out as you can tailor that to however you want it.

It does seem as if this code has been lifted from somewhere else and you've tried to adjust it. That's fine, but it does require you to understand what the original code is doing, and it's nor obvious to me that you have that understanding. You might get more success if you write your code from scratch so that you know where the loops are taking you.

```
Dim data As Variant
Dim fmt As String
Dim output() As Variant
Dim r As Long, x As Long, i As Long

'Define your range
With Sheet1
    data = .Range(.Range("A1"), _
                  .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) _
            .Resize(, 7) _
            .Value2
End With

'Redim output array based on range size.
'Note the + 1 for a header.
ReDim output(1 To UBound(data, 1) * 6 + 1, 1 To 4)

'Write the header.
output(1, 1) = "Product"
output(1, 2) = "Store"
output(1, 3) = "Sales Type"
output(1, 4) = "Qty"

'Transfer the data to output array.
i = 2 'index of ouput array
For r = 3 To UBound(data, 1)
    For x = 0 To 5 'loops the 5 columns in each row
        output(i + x, 1) = data(r, 1) 'product
        output(i + x, 2) = data(1, IIf(x < 3, 2, 5)) 'store
        output(i + x, 3) = data(2, x + 2) 'type
        output(i + x, 4) = data(r, x + 2) 'qty
    Next
    i = i + 6 'increment output index by 6 rows
Next

'Write output to sheet.
Sheet2.Range("A1") _
      .Resize(UBound(output, 1), _
              UBound(output, 2)) _
      .Value = output
```

Comment: I know it's odd (i didn't design it). I made corrections to the marco according to your code. It works like a charm. Thanks a lot !